# What ports does SQL Server need to communicate with a web server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, firewall

If I have a web server trying to communicate to a SQL Server through a firewall, and the firewall is completely closed both ways (inbound and outbound), I know I have to open port 1433 from the web server to the SQL Server in that direction.

However, do I need to open any ports from the SQL Server to the web server for the SQL activities to work?  Does SQL Server respond back with any other ports?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

When the client establishes a TCP/IP connection, a three-way handshake takes place. The client opens a source port and sends traffic to a destination port, which is 1433 by default. The client source port in use is random, but is greater than 1024. By default, when an application requests a socket from the system for an outbound call, a port number between the values of 1024 and 5000 is supplied.

Comment: but what does this mean - do I need to open outbound from ports 1024 --> 5000 ??

Comment: I feel like you might get better answers to this if you migrated the question to the more-narrowly-scoped [dba.se] Stack Exchange site (not that it's off-topic here, just that you might be more likely to get an answer, or a better answer, on that site).

Comment: Most firewalls will automatically allow outbound traffic to endpoints that originate as source addresses. Yes, you will need to allow 1024 - 5000 out but only to the originating address that came in.

Comment: Hmm - I was told specifically that this firewall does not allow ANY outgoing traffic.